# Sites and site owner name

Tags: sharepoint-server, site

I don't know anything about SharePoint, but I've been asked to find the site names and site owners. I've gone onto the server and found under Microsoft SharePoint 2010 products. Under there, there is SharePoint 2010 Central Administration. Is this were I find a list of all the sites and the site owners. If so how?

Sorry if this too simple but all I have seen of SharePoint are the SQL Databases

Answer (score 2):

**1 option.** Site collection administrators.

Open SharePoint Central Administration, navigate to "Application Management" section and click on 'Change site collection administrators'.
So yo will be able to see site collection administrators for each site collection.
http://*CA_URL*/_admin/owners.aspx

**2 option.** Site collection primary administrator.

Open SharePoint Central Administration, navigate to "Application Management" section and click on 'View all site collections'.
So yo will be able to see site collection primary administrator for each site collection.
http://*CA_URL*/_adminSiteCollections.aspx?ReturnSelectionPage=/applications.aspx

**3 option.** Site administrator.

Open SharePoint Central Administration, navigate to "Application Management" section and click on 'View all site collections'.
Open each site in separate window and check permissions. Site settings -> Site permissions. You will be able to see who has full control to the site.
http://*CA_URL*/_adminSiteCollections.aspx?ReturnSelectionPage=/applications.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to SharePoint 2010 Central Administration->Application management->View all site collections, you can choose change web application, check all the site collections' administrator and site collections' name:
[image]

You can access to the site by copying the site URL.